# Code to check all list elements are same returns IndexError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know the index goes over the index of the last member of the group doing it like this but how do I make the function work properly?

Anyway, the function is meant to check if all the members of a list are the same. I have the same problem with another function which is meant to check if the list is in order. It works with everything else but when it's all same numbers it doesn't.

```
i = 0

while i < len(list1):
    if list1[i] == list1[i + 1]:
        i += 1

    else:
        return False

return True
```

Error message is: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Your code is only checking pairwise that all elements are equal to each other, so it's really checking they're all the same value. Use `any()` with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `i` reaches the maximum index within `list1`, obviously `list1[i+1]` will be out of bounds. The immediate fix is to start at 1 (and then of course compare downwards) or stop at `len(list1)-1`.
But you can simplify by comparing all indices to the zeroth.

```
all([list1[0] == x for x in list1[1:]])
```

or as a longhand loop

```
for elem in list1[1:]:
    if elem != list1[0]:
        return False
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is coming from the line
`if list1[i] == list1[i+1]`

The portion of the line above is going out of range. An easy fix is to change the while statement to this:
`while i < (len(list1)-1):`
I believe that should still have the same result as you desire. 
Be careful about accessing future items in a list with a while loop.